# XHTML 1.0 Strict, CSS and img borders

Tags: css, xhtml-1.0-strict

I am using XHTML 1.0 Strict on my website and have the following CSS style on my links:

```
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #447799;
}
```

and my images:

```
a img, img {
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Yet, when I hover over my title banner the bottom border still shows up dotted and blue. Obviously, I can't use border="0" because it is not part of the XHTML 1.0 Strict Doctype.

You can see my site here: [armorycraft.com](http://armorycraft.com)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a class:

```
a.imageAnchor:hover {
    border:none;
}
```

Not the most beautiful solution, but it should work.

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating classes, but I'll try it.

Comment: This method worked. I would prefer a classless method if possible. If I cannot find a working method, I will accept this answer.

Comment: The problem is that the border you see is on the anchor not the image. There is no css-only way to back reference the anchor and remove the border if it contains an image. You could do it with javascript, but I'm guessing that would be overkill.

Comment: There would be CSS-only ways if browsers actually implemented CSS properly.

Comment: @Peter: I'm pretty sure there is no CSS standard to define look aheads, at least in 1 or 2. If you know of one I'd be really interested to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a img:hover, img:hover {border:none; text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is border is attached to the anchor, but then you're setting a border: none to the image.

There's no simple way to avoid this. I'd suggest tweaking the thing a little bit:

```
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #447799;
}

a.image:hover {
    border: none;
}
```

So, add the "image" class to all anchors with images and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

a:hover has border:1, so automaticly `a:hover img` als has border:1

I think this would **fix it**

```
a:hover img{border:0;}
```

now you dont need to make a whole new class for it

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (I think you just forgot the colon (:)

```
a:img, img {
    border: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Good luck!